# How Do I Create a Download Button for Protected Amazon S3 Video Content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, membership

I'd like to add a download button for video files into pages only accessible to members on a membership site I'm designing. I've got the member's permissions for the pages all set up. Don't need help with that.

How would I be able to add a download button for Amazon S3 video content that doesn't allow members to just copy the link to the file and pass it along to their friends/family?

Answer (score 0):

You would create an **Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL**. This generates a URL that allows **time-limited access** to a private object.

However, the link ***can* be used by anyone who has it**. So, yes, they could copy the link and give it to other people and they would be able to access the object within the time limit. But, this isn't particularly different to the member downloading the file themselves and simply giving a copy of the file to somebody else.

There is no in-built capability within Amazon S3 to do as you describe (aside from people having actual AWS credentials, which is not recommended for a web app).

Comment: Gotcha! Well this couldn't be time limited be these videos would be sitting on a member's site indefinitely for members to access until the bussiness owner decides to remove them, so the time limitation wouldn't work.

I guess I will simply have to connect the download link to an actual Amazon S3 URL.

Comment: Your application, when rendering the page for a member, can generate the pre-signed URL on-the-fly (it's just a couple of lines of code). It would grant access for, say, 10 minutes. After that they'd need to refresh the page to get a new link. This limits the time during which other people could download the content if they obtained the link too.